# compare 2 strings seprate by comma in sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, find-in-set

I have a table with fields like this

```
category
--------------
20,14,13,16,19
```

And i have this string:

```
20,16,9,5
```

I want to find products that have this categories

in mysql query.

someone have an idea?

Comment: use WHERE cat IN() for this

Comment: First suggestion: properly normalize your database. Second suggestion: FIND_IN_SET()

Comment: i have tried this two suggestion it doesn't get all the records

Comment: see this.,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678293/extracting-ids-from-a-mysql-table/22678569#22678569

Comment: still doesn't get all the records

Comment: Show the query that you're building rather than expecting us to guess with minimal information and then simply telling us that our guesses don't work

Comment: @MarkBaker, Sadly, 'find_in_set(), according to the manual, does not work if there are commas (',') in the source string. Ok, we can discuss 'sadly' at a later date ('gladly' feels more appropriate to me).

Comment: @RyanVincent - I've actually provided FIND_IN_SET() usage as an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834223/compare-2-strings-seprate-by-comma-in-sql-query/22836935#22836935) to this question, and sadly there are no commas in the source string

Answer (score 0):

We can match the comma separated values ,

Here is a Mysql Query

```
SELECT tens.d*10 + ones.d AS n
FROM (SELECT 0 AS d UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS d UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS d UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS d UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS d UNION ALL
SELECT 5 AS d UNION ALL
SELECT 6 AS d UNION ALL
SELECT 7 AS d UNION ALL
SELECT 8 AS d UNION ALL
SELECT 9 AS d) AS tens
INNER JOIN
(SELECT 0 AS d UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS d UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS d UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS d UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS d UNION ALL
SELECT 5 AS d UNION ALL
SELECT 6 AS d UNION ALL
SELECT 7 AS d UNION ALL
SELECT 8 AS d UNION ALL
SELECT 9 AS d) AS ones
WHERE (tens.d*10 + ones.d) IN (20,14,13,16,19)
AND (tens.d*10 + ones.d) IN ( 20,16,9,5 )
ORDER BY n
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myString = '20,16,9,5';

$sets = array();
foreach(explode(',', $myString) as $individualValue) {
    $sets[] = 'FIND_IN_SET(' . $individualValue. ', category) > 0';
}
$whereClause = implode(' OR ', $sets);

$myQuery = 'SELECT * FROM mytable';
if ($whereClause > '') {
    $myQuery .= ' WHERE ' . $whereClause;
}
```

Comment: There is a small bug in your code: In the foreach loop you should write `$sets[] = `. Apart from that, I think this is a nice solution.

Comment: @Typoheads - fixed thanks; but it's a horrendous solution.... the best solution is normalizing the database; next best solution would be a solution using PDO or MySQLi with prepared statements/bind vars... but I'm guess the poster will be using the MySQL extension.... this quick/dirty suggestion doesn't even test for string values in $myString rather than simply numerics

Comment: OP asked a simple question and got a straight forward answer. I agree, that this is not a nice solution when talking about code quality and software/database design. But an answer here shouldn't be a complete "How to write perfect software" guide, it should answer the question asked. Of course you can try to tell anyone to use prepared statements, PDO, mysqli and to make sure the software is secure, but sometimes it is enough to focus on answering questions. :-)

Answer (score 0):

That depend how your table is but if your table is like : 
id_product | id_category | name | other fields
Try that kind of query:
SELECT

> $category_array= '20,16,9,5';
>   $query = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE id_category IN (" . $category_array . ")";

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete the set of answers here is another one that should come with a health warning.

This assumes the exact same interpretation of the question as: QuentinJadeau.

That is that the input consist of a string which contains a comma separated list of 'categories'.

I have tested it. I tried to set up an 'SQLFiddle' but came second. ;-/ I can post the results.

Sadly, it works as expected, which is similar to the answer 'MarkBaker' provided. The only difference is that this is a function in the database rather than the way he did it. This is the second best way as you can do a lot more when you can generate the complete SQL query dynamically. ;-/

I did this answer 'cos i wanted to write some 'mysql' functions that did something 'useful'.

FIND_IN_COMMA_LIST function

it is a 'mysql' function that takes a comma separated source list, splits it and compare each item with the target comma separated list, using the mysql 'find_in_set' function. It returns the first match it finds.

tested: Server version: Mysql 5.5.16

Example below will return 'x'

```
SELECT find_in_comma_list('1,2,x', 'a,b,c,9,x')

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS FIND_IN_COMMA_LIST;
DELIMITER $$
/*
  needles  => comma separated list of items
  haystack => comma separated list of items

  returns first item in 'needles' list that is found in the 'haystack' list
*/
CREATE
    FUNCTION `testmysql`.`FIND_IN_COMMA_LIST` (needles VARCHAR(128), haystack VARCHAR(255))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
    BEGIN
      DECLARE which INT DEFAULT 0;
      DECLARE result VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
      simple_loop: LOOP
         SET which = which + 1;
         SET result = SPLIT_STR(needles, ',', which);
         IF result = '' THEN
            LEAVE simple_loop;
         END IF;
         IF FIND_IN_SET(result, haystack) != 0 THEN
            LEAVE simple_loop;
         END IF;         
       END LOOP simple_loop;
     RETURN result; 
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

It relies on an other function i found elsewhere.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS SPLIT_STR;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    /*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/
    FUNCTION `testmysql`.`SPLIT_STR`(haystack VARCHAR(255), delim VARCHAR(16), which INTEGER)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
    BEGIN
      RETURN REPLACE(
                     SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(haystack, delim, which),
                               LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(haystack, delim, which - 1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```